# Is it possible to turn this query into a join?

Tags: mysql

This is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM square_achievements_achievements
JOIN square_achievements_achievement_counters ON square_achievements_achievement_counters.SAA_ID = square_achievements_achievements.SAA_ID
JOIN square_achievements_counters ON square_achievements_counters.SAC_ID = square_achievements_achievement_counters.SAC_ID
WHERE square_achievements_counters.eventObject = 'CommentEvent'
AND square_achievements_counters.eventType = 'add'
AND square_achievements_achievements.SAA_ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT square_achievements_achievements.SAA_ID 
    FROM square_achievements_achievements 
    JOIN square_achievements_user_achievements ON square_achievements_user_achievements.SAA_ID = square_achievements_achievements.SAA_ID
    WHERE square_achievements_user_achievements.UID = 83
)
```

If it's possible, would it be more efficient to write this query as a join? If so, how would it be rewritten?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up in my original query - should be SAA_ID = SAA_ID for first join. I'll update my question.

Thanks for help so far. Just working through answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    achievements a
JOIN    achievement_counters ac
ON      ac.saac_id = a.saa_id
JOIN    counters c
ON      c.sac_id = ac.sac_id
WHERE   c.eventObject = 'CommentEvent'
        AND c.eventType = 'add'
        AND a.saa_id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  saa_id
        FROM    user_achievements 
        WHERE   uid = 83
        )
```

This is pretty good.

If you want joins, use this:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    achievements a
JOIN    achievement_counters ac
ON      ac.saac_id = a.saa_id
JOIN    counters c
ON      c.sac_id = ac.sac_id
LEFT JOIN
        user_achievements ua
ON      ua.uid = 83
        AND ua.saa_id = a.saa_id
WHERE   c.eventObject = 'CommentEvent'
        AND c.eventType = 'add'
        AND ua.saa_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Legend! Pretty straight forward now I've seen the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use correlation names to improve the readability of the code

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM square_achievements_achievements a
JOIN square_achievements_achievement_counters b  ON b.SAAC_ID = a.SAA_ID 
JOIN square_achievements_counters c ON c.SAC_ID = b.SAC_ID 
JOIN square_achievements_user_achievements d on d.SAA_ID = a.SAA_ID 
JOIN square_achievements_user_achievements u on d.SAA_ID = u.SAA_ID AND u.UID = 83 
WHERE c.eventObject = 'CommentEvent' 
AND a.eventType = 'add'
```

Comment: Didn't work for me - error using "AND JOIN" and removing the AND gives wrong results.